# Dynamic width with Angular for progress bar not working in IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, dynamic, width, ng-style

I have a progress bar showing me progress in uploads. the CSS works for chrome ,but dosent for IE

```
   <div class="progress-bar">
                            <div style="width: {{media.progress*0.95 + (media.result ? 5 : 0)}}%;" class="progress-bar__bg"></div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ng-style

```
ng-style="{width: (media.progress*0.95) + (media.result ? 5 : 0)+ '%'}"
```

Comment: @janIreal23 Glad to help you.. :)